# how can I check to see if a page is already mounted in wicket?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm configuring an `IInitializer` for a shared package.  I have several mount points that are essentialy the same across applications. I want to mount them in my `IInitializer` but only if they're not already mounted by my application.

So given either `Foo.class` or `"/bar"` as the desired mount point how can I check if the mount point is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe any version of Wicket has this ability built in.  What you *could* do easily is to build the ability into a subclass of `WebApplication` that all your applications then  extend.

The basic process would be to override the [`mountPage`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html#mountPage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method built in `WebApplication` to stash the parameter values in a map (or some data structure of your choosing) before or after calling the super `mountPage`.